# Alternative to Toplevel.deiconify()

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there an alternative to `tk.Toplevel.deiconify()`? I want to show a window for a set amount, then hide it:

```
def show(self, event):
    self.master.geometry("+{x}+{y}".format(x = event.x, y = event.y))
    self.master.deiconify()
    time.sleep(self.howLong/100)
    self.hide()

def hide(self):
    self.master.iconify()
```

However, this shows the `Toplevel` being iconified and deiconified... How can I do this in a different manner or not have it show the process of iconification?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Use `withdraw()` to hide it, and either `iconify()` or `deiconify()` to restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no alternative. `deiconify` is how you make a withdrawn / iconified window visible again.

However, there *is* an alternative to the `iconify` method. Instead of `iconify`, you want to call `withdraw`. Both functions do pretty much what they say: `iconify` tries to convert the window to an icon, the later withdraws it completely from the screen. In both cases, `deiconify` is what you call to restore the window.